# Have a circle around Avatar component

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

In my react-native project, I am using [react-native-elements](https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/avatar.html) library render an Avatar rounded component. Something like below:

```
<Avatar
  size="small"
  rounded
  title="MT"
  activeOpacity={0.7}
/>
```

The above code renders a circle like this:

[image]

Now I need to have a green color circle around the above `Avatar` to make the `Avatar` looks like having a green thick border around it. How to achieve that?

**==== update ====**

I tried:

```
<Avatar
  size="small"
  rounded
  title="User"
  avatarStyle={{
    borderWidth: 3,
    borderColor: 'green',
  }}
/>
```

on iOS it looks like:
[image]

on Android it looks like :
[image]

So, on Android it doesn't look like a circle border, how to resolve that issue on Android?

Comment: What have you tried doing? It looks to me like a simple google search would have come up with the answer I see below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

proxidem's exact solution didn't work for me. The border didn't extend to the corners. This is what worked for me:

```
<Avatar
  size="small"
  rounded
  title="User"
  avatarStyle={{
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'green',
    ...Platform.select({
       android: {
          borderTopWidth: 0,
          borderLeftWidth: 0,
          borderRightWidth: 0,
          borderBottomWidth: 0,
       },
    }),
  }}
/>
```

---

For other trying this solution. If the text doesn't fit, choose a word 2 characters long or shorter or add the `titleStyle` property and change the `fontSize`:

```
titleStyle={{
   fontSize: 10,
   color: 'black',
}}
```

Comment: `borderLeftRadius ` is not a valid style property error raise.

Comment: @Leem.fin How about this?

Comment: On iOS it is fine, on Android it still shows like a square border

Comment: Please see my update in my question, it shows the issue now.

Comment: @Leem.fin I think I've found a fix for the Android issue.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [`avatarStyle`](https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/avatar.html#avatarstyle) prop on your Avatar. This adds style to the underlying image. Example to make a 1px solid green border:

```
  <Avatar
    size="small"
    rounded
    title="MT"
    activeOpacity={0.7}
    avatarStyle={{ borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'green', borderRadius: 5, borderStyle:'solid' }}
  />
```

Comment: This answer produces a square border